# Facebook API get public profile wall posts

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm making a small widget in c# to get the posts from a public facebook page/profile.

I believe you have to get a access token each time you make a request to the api?

I'm confused as to which access token I need and what url request string to use.

This is what I'm using currently but it brings back an unexpected looking key.
access_token=112121212121212|NxG_8djeufhfywhduEjaeU4J-lh4

(I've typed in random characters as an example of the structure).

```
string response = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" + facebook_AppID + "&client_secret=" + facebook_AppSecret + "&grant_type=client_credentials";
string accesstoken = RequestResponse(response);
```

Then when I use that code to get the posts from a wall, using:

```
string urlGetFeed = "https://graph.facebook.com/thepagename?fields=access_token=" + accesstoken2 + ",posts.fields(message,picture)";
```

I get a ERROR : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. Error.

Comment: did  you tried **facebook sdk** ?

Answer (score 3):

For the feed of a Facebook Page, you only need an App Access Token, which is easy to get:

> APP-ID|APP-SECRET

For example:

```
string urlGetFeed = "https://graph.facebook.com/thepagename/feed?access_token=" + [app-id] + "|" + [app-secret];
```

Also, the Access Token is not a value of "fields", it´s a separate parameter.

Comment: that brings back: "Unsupported get request."

Answer (score 0):

The URL you should use is this:

> https://graph.facebook.com/[THE_FACEBOOK_ID]/[WHAT_YOU_WANT]?access_token=[YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]&limit=[THE_LIMIT]

The first part access the Facebook graph.
The second part is the Facebook Id that you want.
The third part is the thing that you want from the Facebook Id that you entered (posts, feed, activities, etc). Here you must be sure that the Access Token has the permissions for what you want to get.
The fourth part is the Access Token that you get and the limit (if you don't set the limit the default limit from Facebook will be used).

Beware of the access token that you-re getting with the first line of code that you posted. That line will give you a short live access token. You should interchange the short live access token here:

> https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=[YUOR_CLIENT_ID]&client_secret=[YOURCLIENT_SECRET]&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=[THE_SHORT_LIVE_ACCESS_TOKEN]

**EDIT:**
What you should do is to include the FB Connect script:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1'</script>
```

and then use this function to take the user to the FB login (if it's not logged in) and then to the authorize page:

```
function createAccessToken()
{
FB.init({appId: '[YOUR APP ID]', status: true, cookie: true});
FB.login(function(response)
{
    if (response.status == 'connected')
    {
        if (response.authResponse.accessToken)
        {
            var token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        }
        else
        {
            alert('You must grant the permissions for this plugin or will not work.');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alert('You must be logged in to Facebook to grant permissions.');
    }
}, { scope: 'read_stream' }); }
```

The token variable inside that function will contain the short lived access token to exchange for the long lived one here:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=[YOUR_CLIENT_ID]&client_secret=[YOURCLIENT_SECRET]&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=[token]
```

Once you get that token go here to get what you want:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[THE_FACEBOOK_ID]/[WHAT_YOU_WANT]?access_token=[YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]&limit=[THE_LIMIT]
```

Comment: That then gives me the error:{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid OAuth access token signature.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190
   }
} Have I got to set some permissions on the app settings?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see that you're getting the Application Token and that's why you can't extend the live of that token, but that token is useless for user operations.